# active directory authentication with status/error code result

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently we (myself and my company) have an asp.net mvc4 page. We wish to utilize a logon page which authenticates via AD. One requirement being with an unsuccessful attempt we give back some information to the user.

The information we would like to have would be something like:

1. Invalid user/pw
2. Account is locked
3. Password expired

This is unfamiliar territory so I'm not sure what .NET libraries may be available. So far I've only come across the [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t2667d1.aspx) but it doesn't seem I will get results beyond a bool.

Is this possible? Any references, suggestions, or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How would you check Invalid user/pw? The user which will access the website is not in that domain?...Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This solution will be hosted in the cloud and we will be controlling the AD, we will know which domain the user is authenticating against(eg. "local.domain"). In my demo project we can certainly tell if a user was unable to validate via the PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials() call. The issue with this solution is we would have no information beyond a True/False result, which obviously doesn't grant you any knowledge to why it was unsuccessful. I may be way off on this one, I'm just looking for suggestions on if there is a way of doing such authentication and getting more detailed results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889.aspx) to validate your credentials first. If `false` is returned, use the static [UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359690.aspx) to find your user then, if found, look to see if the account is locked out using [IsAccountLockedOut()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.isaccountlockedout.aspx).

You might need to extend UserPrincipal yourself to see if the password is expired, I'm not seeing a direct property/method. You can extend it to access the `userAccountControl` attribute directly and check to see if bit `0x800000` is set, which is PasswordExpired. Here is [more information on the userAccountControl values](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144).

Comment: Thanks Joshua! This sounds very reasonable, and looks to be the path I will choose.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have code like this

```
try
{  
  SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
// now what?
}
```

Now in Exception you can deal with LDAP exception type, Here is the List of all LDAP error's.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746530(v=vs.85).aspx

You can identify on the basis of **ADSI Error Value** which type of error you are getting.

But according to me you should give user a single common error like invalid credentials because LDAP error are much hard to deal with.

Cheers.!!